# What is the internal id(name/number) for a saved search record type?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I created a savedSearch for a savedSearch itself via UI with an internal id `customsearch_savedsearch`.

When I'm loading the search using a suiteScript. It shows me an Unexpected error has occured.

```
var search = nlapiLoadSearch(null, 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

The above statement works fine for all other record-types, But fails for a `savedSearch` record type.

What could be the internal id for the `savedSearch` record type?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `null` for the first parameter. When loading or creating a search, you must specify the record type for the search as well. Whatever record type `customsearch_savedsearch` searches for, that's what you would pass in as the first parameter.

So for instance if your saved search is a Customer search, then you would load it by:

```
var search = nlapiLoadSearch('customer', 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the documentation, For nlapiLoadRecord,  if the record type isn't specified provided we give the internal id of the search.  We must give the record type as null. Please have a look at [this](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/section_N3051062.html#bridgehead_N3051604).

Comment: You are not calling `nlapiLoadRecord`. You are calling `nlapiLoadSearch`, and the first parameter for `nlapiLoadSearch` cannot be `null`, or NetSuite does not know what type of search to load.

Comment: Neither can the first parameter of `nlapiLoadRecord` for that matter. It means absolutely nothing to try to load a record type of `null` just like it means absolutely nothing to try to load a search type of `null`.

Comment: you can have a null value on the type param of the nlapiLoadSearch based on SuiteAnswers asnwer ID 10280.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var search = nlapiSearchRecord(null, 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

Documentation:

nlapiSearchRecord(type, id, filters, columns)

Performs a search using a set of criteria (your search filters) and columns (the results). Alternatively, you can use this API to execute an existing saved search. Results are limited to 1000 rows. Also note that in search/lookup operations, long text fields are truncated at 4,000 characters. Usage metering allowed for nlapiSearchRecord is 10 units.

This API is supported in client, user event, scheduled, portlet, and Suitelet scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If `

```
var search = nlapiSearchRecord(null, 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

does not work`use

```
var search = nlapiSearchRecord('', 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct in your statement.  I think the problem is that SuiteScript does not support SavedSearch record types.  Here is a list of [supported types](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/chapter_N3170023.html).

Comment: (1)  Does the saved search run without problems when run through NetSuite UI?  (2) What is the actual search type of the saved search?

Comment: Yes, it does run without any problem.

Comment: What is the actual search type of the saved search?

Comment: **Saved search** itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run this using the above mentioned

```
var search = nlapiSearchRecord(null, 'customsearch_savedsearch',null,null);
```

I've used this in my code and haven't had any issues. Make sure you have the right permissions set on the saved search. To start with, set it as Public. And in the Audience, "select all" roles.

Comment: No, that dint't work aswell. Are you sure the search type is a `SavedSearch`?

Comment: You are right. For a saved search of type SavedSearch this code doesn't work. I had run it with transaction type of savedsearches.

Comment: Yeah, I got others running. But it stumbles on `savedSearches`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. However, Saved Search type (also like Budget record) is not scriptable even you are able to create a saved search. That is why you encountered that error. Most likely, those record types listed on the SuiteScript Record Browser are supported. You may check the list here:

***Note: You should log in first to the account..

**Production**: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/account.html


**Sandbox**: https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/account.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an old question, and I came across it in my own attempt to do the same, but I just tried the following with success:

```
var search = nlapiLoadSearch('savedsearch', 'customsearch_savedsearch');
```

Seemed a little on the nose, but it did the trick.